# program crash due to bad malloc in C

Tags: c, windows, malloc

my program is crashing on the second run on this line:

```
   char* temp_directive = (char *)malloc(7);
```

with this error:

```
Critical error detected c0000374
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in Maman14.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in Maman14.exe or       any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while Maman14.exe has focus.
```

I can't understand why, it always happen on the second run.
I've tried to add free(temp_directive), but it didn't help

anyone famailer with this issue?

Comment: Can you show us the full code?

Comment: This is almost certainly a consequence of a prior `free` or a write outside of memory bounds. Run valgrind to see where it happens.

Comment: What are you doing with `temp_directive` after the `malloc`? Lots of OSs store a bit of info before the pointer returned to enable housekeeping. Perhaps you are messing the housekeeper up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jiangyue/archive/2010/03/16/windows-heap-overrun-monitoring.aspx

Sounds like you ran off the end of the array earlier in the code, and your memory management isn't picking it up until you try to malloc that memory space.

Comment: the code is very long.. that's why I didn't add it. I'm checking for null after the malloc, but the crash happens during the malloc. I'm pretty sure it's related to the first allocation that affecting the second malloc

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, it was caused from a different  realloc . Thanks everyone!